# Can I distinct each column in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

I want to compute the cardinalities of several columns in Hive.

For instance, the table is like

```
------------------------------------------
|   A     |       B      |   C  |    D   |
------------------------------------------
| Windows | C:\Users\aa  |   0  |  1234  |
------------------------------------------
| Windows | D:\Videos    |   1  |  2345  |
------------------------------------------
| Linux   | /usr/local   |   0  |  1234  |
------------------------------------------
|  OS X   | /Users/aa    |   0  |  5678  |
------------------------------------------
```

The cardinalities of columns A, C, D are 3, 2, 3.

The naive solution is to run `SELECT DISTINCT` on each column. However, this seems to be a terrible way. So is it possible to compute these values by scanning the table only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the unique counts for each column you can use `count distinct`

```
select 
    count(distinct a), 
    count(distinct c), 
    count(distinct d)
from mytable
```

Comment: @DANGFan it depends on how you want the results returned i.e. if the distinct values from 3 columns are returned in a single column you could use `select distinct from ... union ...`

Comment: I need three columns in this example.

Comment: @DANGFan i think you would have to do 3 selects then

Comment: I now use `select distinct a, c, d` and write another program to compute.